# Sending custom headers in websocket handshake

Tags: python, websocket

**How to** send custom headers in the first handshake that occurs in the WebSocket protocol?

I want to use custom header in my initial request "****X-Abc-Def : xxxxx**"

WebSocket clients are Python & Android client.

Comment: You need to mention *which* WebSocket clients you are using. A quick google search showed me at least two different ones for android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the python [websocket-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) you can indeed pass custom headers easily - there's a keyword argument `header` available for this; see the following example from the docs:

```
conn = create_connection("ws://echo.websocket.org/", header={"User-Agent": "MyProgram"})
```

**Edit**: Keyword should be `header`, not `headers`.

Comment: "headers" is wrong key word, should be "header".  the following code works for me.                                ```  conn = create_connection("ws://echo.websocket.org/", header={"User-Agent": "MyProgram"}) ```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! this is the only solution that is simple & working !!!

Answer (score 3):

@ThiefMaster got it perfect.
But if you want to add custom headers, you can do that with the argument `header` instead of `headers`.
Hope this helps